# d3.behavior.zoom() moves graph to corner instead of center

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, sunburst-diagram

I want to add a mousewheel zoom to my sunburst:
What I did is I edited this piece of code:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + height * .52 + ")")
    .call(zoom);

function zoomed() {
  svg.attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.transform.x + ',' + d3.event.transform.y + ') scale(' + d3.event.scale + ')');
  //svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

The problem is that when the page loads everything seems to be ok, however when the mouswheel is used to scroll the sunburst ends up in the upper left corner: 
[image]

I was able to fix this by changing this code:

```
function zoomed() {
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + height * .52 + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

The sunburst stays in the middle now, **however** this won't zoom to the place of the cursor and won't allow the user to zoom out further. 
Any suggestions how I can zoom to the cursor place (as in the first code example) without the sunburst disapering in the upper left corner?

*For the full code see [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karimjaafreh/91hqzm93/), it's not working here, however running it local does work.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d3.event.translate` returns an array. Thus, if you want to add those values (`width/2` and `height/2`), you have to add them separately:

```
function zoomed() {
    svg.attr('transform', 'translate(' + (d3.event.translate[0] + width / 2) +
        ',' + (d3.event.translate[1] + height / 2) + ') scale(' + d3.event.scale + ')');
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to use your original zoomed function...

```
function zoomed() {
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate +
        ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

... just break the svg selection, assigning another name for the group:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var foo = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height * .52 + ")")
    .call(zoom);
```

Comment: I tried replacing the "zoomed" function with the one you provided, however zooming out further is still not possible?

Comment: That's **another** issue. I'm addressing only the centering issue here. Please keep it one problem per question.

Comment: I addressed this in my question:  "this won't zoom to the place of the cursor and won't allow the user to zoom out further." I should have added that to the last line for clarity. I will edit it. Could you still adress this issue in your answer?

Comment: I know that you asked that in your question, that's precisely what I'm saying here: ask just **one problem** per question. I'm answering just the center issue. If you want to improve the zoom out extent, simply do `.scaleExtent([0.1, 10])`.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the standard d3.event.translate and d3.event.scale in the Zoomed function, like this:

```
function zoomed() {
svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

It all worked fine except the whole sunburst jumped to the top left when I first scrolled. It corrected itself after I dragged it back to the middle but it was annoying.

I struggled with this for hours. Eventually I solved it by changing the viewBox attribute on the svg:

```
.attr({viewBox: "" + (-width / 2) + " " + (-height / 2) + " " + width + " " + height})
```

I got the idea from this example: [Basic Sunburst](http://bl.ocks.org/nitaku/5c05241a724bd559180a)